# How do I escape the markdown parser for certain pieces of text?

Tags: markdown, textile

I'm using textile to generate HTML for a specific page and in the copy, there is a need for (c) to be generated without the copyright symbol. Unfortunately, textile always does it.

Is there a way in textile to escape the parsing it does to change it (I know I could put spaces on either side of the "c," but that doesn't look nice)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `<notextile></notextile>` tags in the markdown will cause the parser to skip whatever is between those two tags. [RedCloth docs](http://redcloth.org/textile/html-integration-and-escapement/#no-textile)

Comment: `==` works in Basecamp's editor, but `<notextile></notextile>` does not.

Comment: This didn't work for me. (I'm using a markdown plugin for Atom text editor--probably the problem is that the plugin doesn't support this.)

Comment: @6005 for markdown you can use `\*` for printing `*`

Answer (score 14):

Also using `&#40;c)` will yield (c) rather than ©.

Answer (score 0):

for textile：I attempted various formatting options such as `== ^2^ ==`, `<notextile> ^2^</notextile>`, `notextile.`, `notextile..`, and `@ ^2^ @`, but none of them produced the desired result. Finally, I found that using `\^2\^` correctly outputs `^2^`.