# Escaping (c) in Rmd (R markdown)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to use (c) in an .Rmd file and it renders as a copyright symbol after knitting.  How can I make it render as just `(c)` not ©?

Comment: Wouldn't this happen even without knitr in markdown?

Comment: I don't know but I can manually go into the .html file and change it to `(c)` and it will render correctly when opened in the browser.

Comment: Tyler, have a look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905520/how-do-i-escape-the-markdown-parser-for-certain-pieces-of-text

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks.  THis is a duplicate and I'm voting to close.